# Nice way to update an object in Bicep?

Tags: azure-bicep

I need a little bit of help around this.

I have

```
var sourceIpGroups = json(loadTextContent('../../modules/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups/ipgroup-aml.json'))
```

The file contain is :

[
"10.0.0.0", "20.0.0.0"
]

I also have this :
var baseNetwork = json(loadTextContent('../../modules/Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/baseNetwork.json'))

The file contain :

```
[{
    "name": "BaseNetworkRules",
    "priority" : 100,
    "ruleCollections": [
        {
            "name": "DCAccess",
            "ruleCollectionType": "FirewallPolicyFilterRuleCollection",
            "priority": 100,
            "action": {
                "type": "Allow"
            },
            "rules": [
                {
                    "ruleType": "NetworkRule",
                    "name": "DCAccess",
                    "ipProtocols": [
                        "UDP"
                    ],
                    "sourceAddresses": [],
                    "sourceIpGroups": [],
                    "destinationAddresses": [],
                    "destinationIpGroups": [],
                    "destinationFqdns": [],
                    "destinationPorts": ["53"]
                }
            ]
            }]
            }]
```

I want to be able to update the value at this position before creation
baseNetwork[0].ruleCollections[0].rules[0].sourceIpGroups
with the array in the first file.

What would be the proper way to define my variable to "update" my basenetwork object?

thanks!
Jessica

Comment: Can't you use parameters rather than loading values from files ? it sounds a bit over complicated: what is the reason to get the value using loadTextContent ?

Comment: also not related but you could the `loadJsonContent` function directly

Comment: can you show all the sample code, I do not think you are following the best practices. This scenario shouldn't be so complicated.

Comment: It would be easy if you can directly assign the value to sourceIps in the format `baseNetwork[0].ruleCollections[0].rules[0].sourceIpGroups = sourceIpGroups;` Is that works for you? @JLA

Answer (score 2):

The value of `baseNetwork[0].ruleCollections[0].rules[0].sourceIpGroups` can be set by setting the value of `sourceIpGroups` to the array in the first file.

```bash
baseNetwork[0].ruleCollections[0].rules[0].sourceIpGroups = sourceIpGroups;
```

*Your code looks like below:*

```bash
var sourceIpGroups = JSON.parse(loadTextContent('../../modules/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups/ipgroup-aml.json'));
var baseNetwork = JSON.parse(loadTextContent('../../modules/Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies/baseNetwork.json'));
baseNetwork[0].ruleCollections[0].rules[0].sourceIpGroups = sourceIpGroups;
```

I tried deploying a sample network firewall policy by referring to this [template](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/firewall/quick-create-ipgroup-template.md) and was successful as shown below.

[image]

[image]